# Search Query with wildcards in Date

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to search DB for records based on Date. But the search is based in month and year. i.e `mm/yyyy` and dd is to be wild-card.

My search query looks like this:

```
Select ucid, uc_name, From (UC_Table1)
where UC_Date like To_Date('11/*/2011','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

this gives me the following error:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected, So obviously it doesn't like `*` or `%` or `_` or `?`  as wild-cards for dd.

Answer (score 4):

Wildcards do not work like that within a function.  The `To_Date()` function parses out the `*` before the `LIKE` has a chance to see it. Consider:

```
SELECT ucid, uc_name
FROM UC_Table1
WHERE UC_Date >= To_Date('11/01/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
   AND UC_Date < To_Date('12/01/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The query I'm using is:
    Select ucid, config_clob,Created_TS From (Config_Clob)
    where to_Char(Config_Clob.Created_TS,'mmddyyyy') like '11%2011'

Comment: If the table is of any size, you would be better to do it as Adam suggested ( with an index on UC_Date )

Comment: @MatthewWatson without putting `@sloggers1894` they will not be notified of your message.  By default it is only the person who owns the question/answer you're commenting on, and up to one person you specify with @name.